# What does SQL Server sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks tell me?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have a server broker application I inherited that abends with a false negative.

I think it is using `sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks` incorrectly, and I want to validate that my understanding of what that view shows is correct.

Can I assume that this view is showing tasks being activated, and no so much those that were activated, but are now in the process of completing?

The procedure I have monitors for completion of processing by looking for when there are no entries in `sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks` for that queue.

This appears to work (*mostly*), **except** occasionally at the end when processing in the queue is winding down.

The row in that table seems to disappears before the final message in the queue has completed.

And unfortunately, as this uses the fire and forget anti-pattern, I can't really at this time do more than make the polling monitor a bit smarter.

Comment: Can you describe your process a little more and what problem you're having? It seems like you're trying to figure out if there are messages still left in the queue that your activation procedure isn't processing. But I might be missing something…

Comment: I am not really looking to see if there are messages in the queue. The final message has been received, and the activated process that grabbed it had not completed running. The monitor procedure that sent the message needs to know what the status of the final activated process is before it exits with a error status.

Comment: I would expect there to be a little bit of lag between the last message being processed and the activated procedure completing based on what "best practices" are with respect to putting the `receive` in a `waitfor` with a timeout. I'm still trying to figure out what you're trying to do though - if you're trying to see if all of your messages got processed, do a `select count(*) from dbo.youQueue`. Additionally, you may want to put logic in your activated procedure to update a status table based on the processing status of that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That view doesn't do much apart from:

> Returns a row for each stored procedure activated by Service Broker.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175029.aspx

Not sure if you have looked at the code, but I think a better usage of it is to combine it with **sys.dm_exec_sessions**

```
select
 at.spid
,DB_NAME(at.database_id) AS [DatabaseName]
,at.queue_id
,at.[procedure_name]
,s.[status]
,s.login_time
from
    sys.dm_broker_activated_tasks at
inner join
    sys.dm_exec_sessions s
on
    at.spid = s.session_id;
```

Another good place to troubleshoot Service Broker is sys.transmission_queue. You will see every message sent there until there is an acknowledgement that it was received.